# Ramp WebAudio gain, while playback is stopping and starting?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have an application where audio playback may be starting and stopping, and there are UI controls to ramp the gain to zero or nonzero values.  I'm scheduling playback using [AudioBufferSourceNode.start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start), and modulating gain using [AudioParam.linearRampToValueAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime).  Playback is sometimes scheduled for a future time.  The problem I'm having is that the ramp function only seems to set values when playback is currently happening; so, if we try to set the gain value e.g. between playback being scheduled and playback starting, the new values are lost.  I could do a bunch of timing checks, and either ramp or directly set gain depending on whether playback is happening, but this can get messy, and I was wondering whether there was an alternative way to do this which would work independently of playback starting and stopping.

Here is a test case: we create a one-second noise buffer and play it, while also ramping gain to zero.  If playback is scheduled for after the ramp has ended (one second), the gain value never gets set and remains at the default, nonzero value.

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var SR = ctx.sampleRate;
var buffer = ctx.createBuffer(1, SR, SR);
var channelData = buffer.getChannelData(0);
for (var i=0; i<SR; i++) {
  channelData[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
}
var bufferNode = ctx.createBufferSource();
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
bufferNode.buffer = buffer;
bufferNode.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime + 1);
//XXX if start_delay is greater than 1 (the ramp duration), 
// the gain is never changed and remains at 1.
var start_delay = 0;
bufferNode.start(ctx.currentTime + start_delay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to have been caused by a bug in Chrome, which was fixed in Chrome 57.  Here is the bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647974

The following comment has a workaround for older versions of Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647974#c9

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here:

1. The behavior of `linearRampToValueAtTime` without a preceeding automation event was originally not well-specified.  This has since been fixed in the WebAudio spec.  Don't know the status of various browsers on this, but I think Chrome does this correctly.
2. The automation of the gain node should work as you expect. If it doesn't file a bug against your browser vendor.